# How to do a synchronous Jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronization

I have a webpage with tabs inside it, and when I click on a tab it should load a text editor then get the text from a file and put it inside the text editor.

However, the text doesn't load synchronously, it behaves asynchronously. Even though I made something that should be synchronous.

here's the code :

```
function init(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({heightStyle: "content",collapsible: true});
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs(
    {
        activate: function(click,ui) {
            ui.oldPanel.children("#editor").remove();
            ui.newPanel.load("be.htm",function(response, status, xhr){
                $("#editor").css("width","100%");
                $("#editor").css("height","500px");
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "./load_content.php",
                    async: false,
                    data: "name="+ui.newTab.text(),
                    success: loadContent
                });
            });
        }
    }
    );
}

function loadContent(contenu){
    alert(contenu);
    $("#textBox").html(contenu);
}
```

as requested, i tried to make a MCVE

here is be.htm , the "editor" (i took out all that wasn't necessary)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rich Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is bv.html, the webpage where the code must appear (the jquery script are lcoally stored on my computer so you'll have to input your own paths, sorry

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Projet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="YOURPATHHERE/Projet/jquery-ui.css">- -->
    <script src="YOURPATHHERE/Projet/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="YOURPATHHERE/Projet/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="YOURPATHHERE/Projet/bv.js"></script>
    <script src="YOURPATHHERE/Projet/jstree.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bv.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        init();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Onglet1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Onglet2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Onglet3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

i gave you the full javascript code i have so far.

and finally here's the php called by ajax :

```
<?php

$filename=$_GET['name'];
$data = file_get_contents("./".$filename);
echo $data;
return $data;
?>
```

and btw, i'm sorry if you find this code ugly, but i'm a starter as i already told.

Comment: *"even tough i made something that should be synchronou"* What makes you think you did that? `load` is not synchronous, and you've used `load`. The part within the `load` success callback will happen synchronously, but not the `load`.

Comment: Why would you want it to be synchronous? Doing synchronous ajax requests locks up the browser UI during the request, leading to a poor UX.

Comment: then how can i wait for my document loading to end before doing the next lines of code ? i readed on the site that calling the code in a callback function would do the trick ... if you have another wayaround so the text would load correctly inside the editor as i want it to do then tell me, i'm pretty new at javascript

Comment: Your best bet is *not to try to make it synchronous*. Again: Why would you want that? Instead, just trigger whatever it is you want to have happen next from within the ajax completion callback(s).

Comment: my actual problem is that sometimes the text have loaded and the editor has not loaded, which lead me to not put the text inside it when i want it to do. then afterward the editor load with the sample text and not the text coming from the file.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen with the above, assuming the `load` loads the editor, whatever that is. Perhaps if you create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), we can help.

Comment: i added a MCVE, check it out if you can please, i'd be grateful :)

Comment: Your code refers to an element with the `id` `"editor"`, but there isn't any element with that `id` in your markup.

Comment: the problem seem to be solved. thanks you, i forgot to edit this code when i changed the loading function (i previously used an iframe but that was bad too)